# How to Force Current User to a Field in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Consider I have models, a serializer and a viewset as below:

```py
# models.py

class Foo(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, models.CASCADE, related_name="bars")

# serializers.py

class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault(),
        queryset=User.objects.all(),
    )

    class Meta:
        fields = ["pk", "owner"]

# viewsets.py

# registered to /api/foos/
class FooViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = FooSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Foo.objects.all()
```

So, when I send a POST request to `/api/foos/` with an empty body, it creates a `Foo` instance with its `owner` field set to the current logged-in user, which is fine.

However, I also want to totally ignore what the currently authenticated user sends as a value to `owner`. For example, if I do a POST request to `/api/foos/` with body `user=5` (another user, basically), `CurrentUserDefault` sets the `Foo.owner` to that user, which is not the behavior I want to have.

I always want to have the current authenticated user as the value of the field `owner` of a new `Foo` instance, or, in other words, I want `FooSerializer.owner` field to be set as currently authenticated user as a value and *ignore what is sent on POST request as a value of `owner`*.

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

---

## Environment

- django ^2.2
- djangorestframework ^3.12.4

Comment: I think the documentation gives a nice way to have this working: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#advanced-field-defaults. "Using a standard field with read_only=True, but that also includes a default=… argument. This field will be used in the serializer output representation, but cannot be set directly by the user.", meaning you could just mark the field as read only

Comment: This causes `django.db.utils.IntegrityError` with `x violates not-null constraint` error, at least in my codebase. The answer below, however, works for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you don't want `owner` to be modifiable via your serializer, I'd suggest you to remove the field from the serializer or make it [read-only](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#read_only).

You can then set the owner using the serializer's `save` method that allows you to [inject additional data](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save).

A good place for this in your example would be the [`perform_create` method](https://www.cdrf.co/3.12/rest_framework.viewsets/ModelViewSet.html#perform_create) of your `ModelViewSet`. For example:

```py
class FooViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = FooSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Foo.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```